# webpack dev server + spring boot + oauth2

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, keycloak

When app is running, we have following flow:

1. User enters url 'host:8080/book/123'
2. Backend reveals that user is not authenticated and redirects to keycloak.
3. User enters password+name and logins.
4. User is redirected back to 'host:8080/book/123'

This works fine, however I do not understand how in this case I can use webpack-dev-server. The problem is (i.e. webpack dev server is on port 8090):

1. "First" request to host:8090/book/123 should be redirected to backend for login
2. "Second" request should be not redirect, index.html should be returned.

Can I make this setup without modifying code?

UPDATE.
As a workaround: 
defined variable using DefinePlugin, in js this variable is used to use different login processes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is over 1 yo but maybe someone can still use the answer. Using different development setup always introduce some things like this. Modern techniques like that introduced in spring boot devtools allow you to do something cool. Have you considered doing something like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921629/springboot-webpack-dev-server-does-not-change-localhost-bundle-file-after-reb) or [here](https://medium.com/@l1ambda/webpack-a-spring-boot-app-with-instant-page-refresh-5d051a09d26f) instead?